# JQuery Datepicker with nested Resources Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, datepicker, nested-forms

I try to use the datepicker function in my app wich runs with Rails 3.1. I got it working if I use the following in my application.js file:

```
$(function(){
     $("#exam_deadline").datepicker();
});
```

Now I have a nested Resource and tried a lot of things to get this working for it as well, but didn´t have any success. With some research I found that a possible solution would be this:

```
  $(function(){
    $('.datePicker').datePicker();
  });
```

But if I add the class to my fields, it doesn´t even work for the exam_deadline anymore. I´m not so familiar with Javascript and I hope, someone can tell me, what I´m doing wrong. 
This are the snippets from my views and .js:
js:

```
function remove_fields (link) {
  $(link).prev("input[type=hidden]").val("1");
  $(link).closest(".fields").hide();    
}

function add_fields(link, association, content) {
  var new_id = new Date().getTime();
  var regexp = new RegExp("new_" + association, "g");
  $(link).parent().before(content.replace(regexp, new_id));
}
```

view :
exam:

```
<%= semantic_form_for @exam do |f| %>
<%= f.inputs do%>   
<%= f.input :deadline,  :as => :string, 
       :start_year => Time.now.year, :label => "Anmeldefrist", 
       :order =>[:day,:month,:year], :class => 'datePicker'%>
<% end %>   
<%= f.semantic_fields_for :examdates do |builder|%>
  <%= render "examdate_fields", :f => builder %>
<% end %>
<p>
  <%= link_to_add_fields "Termin hinzufügen", f, :examdates %>
</p>

<%end%>
```

examdate_fields:

```
<%= f.inputs :class => 'fields' do%>
<%= f.input :date, :label =>"Termin", 
    :as => :string,
    :order =>[:day,:month,:year], :start_year => Time.now.year,
    :class=>"datePicker" %>
<%= link_to_remove_fields "Entfernen", f %>
<%end%>
```

my application.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
   <title><%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "Untitled" %></title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css",
    "application", "formtastic.css", "formtastic_changes.css" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js", 
    "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js",   "application" %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
    <%= yield(:head) %>
  </head>
...
```

Thanks in advance for every little tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after a lot of trying I got it. I changed the js to:

```
$(function(){
  $(".datePicker").datepicker();
  $('#ui-datepicker-div').hide();
  $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat = 'dd M yy' 
});
```

and my view:

```
<%= f.input :date, 
  :label =>"Termin", 
  :as => :string,
  :order =>[:day,:month,:year], 
  :start_year => Time.now.year, 
  :input_html => {:class =>"datePicker" }%>
```

Now it works:) I hope it helps others who struggle with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick guess. You're using single quotes on your try with a class name.

If that doesn't solve the issue I would try to stick with Ids instead of classnames (I don't know whether datepicker can still reference them properly with class selectors). You would just need another Id for every input and dynamically created javascript (a datepicker for every dynamically created input), instead of a static js file.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. The single quotes weren´t the problem. Could you tell me, how the function would look like, if I use an Id? In the Input field, do I just have to replace :class with Id or do I have to put it somewhere else? Could it also have something to do with the fact, that I already have the class "fields" in the inputs tag?